# Is it possible for 'pre-big bang' empty space to have the property of being able to spawn matter and/or energy into existence?

Tags: big-bang-theory

.. and if so, wouldn't this also mean that during this event, time would be created as a collateral, as a canvas for this property to manifest?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we have no idea, what could be a "pre big-bang empty space".

Comment: How does the fact, that we don't know something YET make it off-topic? Isn't asking questions about things we don't know (yet) the concept behind asking questions? Isn't asking the first step on the path to find out?

Comment: The point of my question was, that if empty space had this proposed property of spawning energy/matter, thus time, it could actually be this "pre big-bang empty space".

Comment: If we don't know it yet, we can't answer your question in any useful way beyond "don't know" (at best).  We do *not* allow speculative answers or discussion or opinion only answers.  So it's off topic here.

Comment: In standard Big Bang theory, space and time didn't exist before the Big Bang, so you need to explain what you mean by "'pre-big bang' empty space".

Comment: So @ PM 2Ring, if we go ahead with standard Big Bang Theory assumption, that space and and time did not exist (I called it pre-Big bang empty space, to grasp it in some way), could we say it had properties? Could we say on of these was the capability to spawn matter/energy/time? (Yes, Im repeating my question) :)

Comment: @Marko36 Might read this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/32426

Comment: @Marko36 - since space and time did not exist, you are asking about the properties of nothingness.  If nothing has a property it stops being nothing

Comment: Space itself was created with the Big Bang. There was no "empty space" before the Big Bang because there was not any kind of space at all. Nothing existed before that, not even nothingness. Existence itself starts with the Big Bang.

Comment: Or to put it in the OP’s own terms: there is no such thing as “pre” Big Bang.

Comment: Well, well, a question related to Big Bang is off-topic on Astronomy, because we don§t know what came before (if anything). Where to post it, then?